# Cannot run tumblr-rb ruby script in bash script from crontab

Tags: ruby, bash, cron

I wrote the following bash script named `/home/pi/test.sh` (that uses the ruby gem "tumblr-rb"):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "starting script"
/usr/local/bin/tumblr post /home/pi/test.jpg --host=myhost.tumblr.com --credentials=/home/pi/.tumblr 
echo "end of script"
```

If I run it from the command line, I get:

```
starting script
Post was successfully created! Post ID: 82238814640
end of script
```

And my picture gets posted to Tumblr. Then if I put the bash script in my pi user's crontab with `* * * * * /home/pi/test.sh`, I get the following cron output e-mailed to me:

```
starting script
end of script
```

And nothing gets posted to Tumblr. Why does nothing happen?

Answer (score 0):

Cron passes a minimal set of environment variables to your jobs.
You can use a simple shell to check the environment crontab provided:

```
* * * * * env > /home/pi/cron_env.dat
```

Try to add the full path of your ruby binary to execute the ruby script.

You can also set the PATH variable in the crontab file, which will apply to all cron jobs. e.g.

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
* * * * * bash -c /home/pi/test.sh
```

Comment: This was very helpful, but it didn't resolve the issue yet. I added the PATH from my env to the crontab and the full path to ruby in the bash script. Same result.

Comment: No dice. What does the -c option do?